# appending text to a global variable

Tags: python, append

I am having problems with global variables in Python; i have defined a global variable in a method and i am trying to append some text to it from another method.

method1:

```
def method1():
    global v
    v="hi "
    print v
```

method2:

```
def method2():
   print v # prints `hi`
   v +="go home"
   print v # doesn't append
```

how i call:

```
method1()
method2()
```

expected output is `hi go home`, but i am not getting the expected output.

How can i solve this ? I need to append some text in `method2()` and display it.

Comment: global variables are highly frowned upon except for very limited applications.  Would you like to see ways to accomplish this without global variables?

Comment: Your function names are also confusing. `method1` and `method2` sound like they should be methods of a class, not top-level functions.

Comment: Also, why did you add the `global v` in `method1`? If you knew it was necessary there, why didn't you think to put it in `method2`? If you didn't know it was necessary, why put it there in the first place?

Answer (score 6):

declare `v` as global:

```
>>> def method1():
...     global v
...     v="hi "
... 
>>> def method2():
...     global v
...     v +="go home"
... 
>>> method1()
>>> method2()
>>> v
'hi go home'
```

Comment: Why can't i print it after i concatenate ? Is there any other i could do it?

Comment: @user1315906, You can `print` it.

Answer (score 2):

falsetru's answer shows exactly what you need to do to make this work: a global variable has to be declared global in *every* function, not just one function.

However, as Brionus suggested in a comment, that's probably not the best way to solve this. Instead of a global variable, just pass parameters and return values around. For example:

```
def function1():
    v = "hi "
    print v
    return v

def function2(v)
    v += "go home "
    print v
    return v

v = function1()
v = function2(v)
```

The advantage of this is that you can create multiple strings and manipulate them independently. For example:

```
v1 = function1()
v2 = function1()
v2 = function2(v2)
v2 = function2(v2)
print v1
print v2
```

At the end, you've got `"hi go home go home "` in `v2`, but you've also still got `"hi "` in v1. With a global variable, you can only have one value at a time; as soon as you change it, you've lost the old value.

---

There are other possible designs for organizing components and sharing or passing state between them. For example, you could wrap the state (the `v` variable) in a class, with the methods as instance methods of that class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def method1(self):
        self.v = "hi "
        print self.v
    def method2(self):
        self.v += "go home "
        print self.v

my_object = MyClass()
my_object.method1()
my_object.method2()
```